# MVC app not writing log files when deployed on IIS 7.5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, deployment, iis-7.5, web-deployment

When an exception occurs in my MVC app, the code creates a folder named **Logs** (if one doesn't exist already) under the ~ (app root) folder and under this folder, it creates a file (if one doesn't exist already) called MyApp.Exceptions.log. It then appends the exception information to this.

This is my home-grown logger. Works like a charm when I deploy locally.

On the remote server, though, no logs are generated. Not even the **Logs** folder is created.

I have given Read/Write/Modify permissions to IIS_USR (or whatever it is called) account for the whole ~ folder.

Please help.

Below are some details about my deployment environment.

**Web Server:** IIS 7.5

**.NET Framework:** v4

**MVC version:** 4

**Windows Server:** Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I realized that I had to grant permissions to the user **ASP.NET v4.0**, which was the name of the **Application Pool** / **Identity** under which my application was registered / running.

That solved the problem.